# PHPMailer 500 on $mail variable creation

Tags: php, phpmailer

tl;dr; Last echo of the code snippet is never reached. Any tips?

Environment: IIS running on Windows Server 2012r2, PHP installed with IIS PHP Manager

I've just downloaded PHPMailer, placed all the php files included in the src folder in C:\PHP\includes, and uncommented the line in my PHP.ini that allows me to use the includes folder. I've created a short PHP file to test things, and now I'm getting a 500 error when the new PHPMailer variable is declared. My echos (tests) are being returned up until that point. What could I be missing? Has anyone run into this? Any pointers for things I could check?

```
<?php
    echo "about to require phpmailer\r\n";
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    echo "done with the require statement\r\n";

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    echo "created the mail variable\r\n";
?>
```

Comment: Read this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#first-time

Comment: and https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks. The tip from the Troubleshooter to enable warnings and errors has confirmed that the PHPMailer php library hasn't been properly loaded. Now I'm Googling that error. ("Class 'PHPMailer' not found in <my php file>")

Comment: It turns out I was missing a "use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;" in my PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing a `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;` before my `require` line.